# The pre-decrement operator is not loading the decremented value in Java

Tags: java

I have the following simple code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 1, j = 10;
        do {
            if (i++ > --j) continue;
        } while (i < 5);
        System.out.println("i=" + i + " j=" + j);
    }
```

The output is: i=5 j=6

This result shows that the values of "i" and "j" that the if statement have used in the first "do" iteration were the original values (i.e. 1 for i, and 10 for j). I can understand that for the i++, but I do not understand why --j in the if statement was 10 instead of 9 in the first iteration. What I thought is that --j should be 9 instead of 10 because it is a pre-decrement.
Can someone clarify?
Thanks!

Comment: It is 9. I don't know how you're getting that it's 10.

Comment: The output shown occurs if the pre-decrement works. It compares 1 to 9, 2 to 8, 3 to 7, and 4 to 6, then leaves the loop with i = 5 and j=6. What makes you think the pre-decrement operator isn’t working?

Comment: When you find yourself in situations like this, you might find it helpful to explore the behavior of smaller fragments of this in the Java interactive shell, `jshell`.  Starting with `i++` and `++i`, then building to bigger constructs like the loop.  The interactive shell encourages you to break things down into smaller chunks, making it easier to see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks @BrianGoetz , I will check the jshell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite simple to me:

The loop runs 4 times before `i<5==false`

i: 1+4=5

j: 10-4=6

Clear enough?

Comment: The loop runs 5 times !

Comment: no, each loop increments `i` by one. at the end of the fourth run `i=5` and hence the loop exits.

Comment: Yes. It is indeed 4. I guess used my snippet as a reference which was not intended to be equivalent to the initial post. Will leave my comment as-is though! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for clarifying; I got the point as the following:

1. First "do" iteration: i=1, j=9, After the if is executed, i=2 and j=9
2. Second iteration: i=2, j=8, After the if, i=3 and j=8
3. Third iteration: i=3, j=7, After the if, i=4 and j=7
4. Fourth iteration: i=4, j=6, After the if, i=5 and j=6
   At this point i is no longer < 5 and exits the loop with i=5 and j=6.

Comment: Not really. Believe it should be (1,10) (2,9),(3,8),(4,7) and finally (5,6).

Comment: That was the controversial point actually. After checking the compiled code, it is confirmed that the decreased value of 'j' is used in the 'if' statement. So it starts with (1, 9).

Comment: Yes. My bad. Just verified it my self. Will leave the comment as it is though. Also the loop runs 5 times.  (c :1, d:9, a:2, b:9), (c :2, d:8, a:3, b:8), (c :3, d:7, a:4, b:7), (c :4, d:6, a:5, b:6), (c :5, d:5, a:6, b:5). Will elaborate in my answer.

Comment: Update #2. It runs 4 times! The code snippet in my answer is only intended to demonstrate the behaviour of the post-increment. Not an exact re-construction of the original loop.

Answer (score 0):

I ran this code on my computer and your code works correctly. Try to write:

```java
if (--j==9) {
    System.out.println("yup");
}
```

`yup` will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

My initial impression was that the sequence would be -

- (1,10) (2,9),(3,8),(4,7) and finally (5,6).

However a quick check indicates that is not the case.

Given -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 1, c = 0;
    int b = 10, d = 0;
    
    do {
        
        c = (a++); 
        d= (--b);
        System.out.println("c :"+ (c) +", d:"+ (d)  +", a:"+(a) + ", b:"+(b));
        if ( c > d) {
            System.out.println("(c > d) !!");
            continue;
        }
    }while( c<5);
    System.out.println("c :"+ (c) +", d:"+ (d));
}
```

The output is -

```
c :1, d:9, a:2, b:9
c :2, d:8, a:3, b:8
c :3, d:7, a:4, b:7
c :4, d:6, a:5, b:6
c :5, d:5, a:6, b:5
c :5, d:5
```

At no point is the "`continue`" called since the criteria (LHS > RHS) is never satisfied.

In general, its not a good idea to mix the two conventions precisely due to the confusion it creates.

As an added precaution, its better to have the increment operation as an independent step (without any assignment) for the same reason (unless the code is a performance intensive one).

```
int i = 1;
i++;
System.out.println("i :"+i);
```

Comment: you have an error in your logic: `a=(c++)` sets the value of `c` to the value of `a` before it is incremented, hence your check `c<5` turns `true` one iteration too late. `a<5` would terminate one iteration earlier.

Comment: Am not trying to prove any logic as such. Only documenting the behaviour so that it can be referred quickly. The behaviour you mention is self-documented (so-to-speak) in the first output where the value for 'c' is 1.

Comment: @Jan - PS: Yes. The case is indeed that the above snippet is not strictly equivalent to the problem-statement. But think it does nicely demonstrate the fact on how the post-increment works.